# SQL Inner Join returns strange results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Ok, I have two tables in my database. I have a table books, that has (id, title, author), and I have another table orders which has (id, bookid, authorid, fromdate, todate).

I am just to get all the books, that are available to order/reserve. Meaning, all the books from the books table, where in the orders table there should be no orders.bookid the same as any books.id

So, I've made this query:

```
SELECT books.title, books.author 
FROM books 
INNER JOIN orders 
ON orders.bookid ORDER <> books.id
```

looks like I've found it, looks to work with:

```
SELECT * FROM books LEFT JOIN orders ON books.id = orders.bookid WHERE orders.bookid IS NULL
```

What do you think ?

So, I have 6 books in my example, with ids 1-6, and I have in orders table two orders, where the booksid(s) are 3 and 4. Now, if I run my query it shows me the books from 1-2 and 5-6 (twice), and also the books 3 and 4 once.

I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong, but anyway, I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Sample data and desired output might be helpful in clarifying what you're after.

Comment: Do not put the answer into the question; write an answer below.

Comment: @GoatCO That query is correct.

Comment: @CL I see from the edit history that the second query was added in the middle, and the incorrect output relates only to the first query.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT b.title, b.author 
FROM books b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o WHERE o.bookid = b.id);
```

Comment: It's `NOT EXISTS`, but not sure why you've been downvoted without explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Why not give your tables alias names and join on the id column?

`SELECT 
B.TITLE,
B.AUTHOR
FROM BOOKS B 
INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON B.ID = O.BOOKID`

Comment: This will not provide the desired output.